# Inserted only once in mysql db.

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have the following code to add data to my database. It seems correct any everything is working fine, however it adds only once to the database and, after that it tells me that the data has been saved into database correctly, but when you want to check it to see if it has been added, I can see that its hasnt been added.

insert.php

```
<?php   
            session_start();
            $server = "";
            $user_name = "";
            $password = "";
            $database = "";
            $id = $_SESSION['id'];
            $res_name = $_SESSION['username'];

            $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
            $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);
            if ($db_found) {
                $SQL = "INSERT INTO [db_table] (ID,name,category,dish_name,explanation,ingredients,price) 
                VALUES ('$id','$res_name','$_POST[cat]','$_POST[dname]','$_POST[about]','$_POST[ing]','$_POST[num]')";
                $result = mysql_query($SQL);

                mysql_close($db_handle);

                print "Records added to the database";
                echo "<BR>";
                echo "<a href='newitem.php'>Back to main page</a>";

            }
            else {
                mysql_close($db_handle);
            }
          ?>
```

and in my html form:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="inser.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="dname" name="dname" class="input-medium" placeholder="Dish Name">
    <?php
    $server = "";
    $user_name = "";
    $password = "";
    $database = "";
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $res_name = $_SESSION['username'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);
    if ($db_found) {

        $SQL = "SELECT category from Category where Rest_ID = '".$id."'";           
        $result = mysql_query($SQL,$db_handle) or die(mysql_error());
        $i = 0;
        echo "<select id='cat' name='cat'> <option selected='selected'>Select</option>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $i = $i + 1;
            echo "<option>".$i.". $row[category]</option>";
        }
        echo '</SELECT>';
    }
    else {
        mysql_close($db_handle);
    }
    //echo $id;
    ?>
    <input type="text" id="ing" name="ing" class="input-medium" placeholder="Ingredients">
    <input type="text" id="about" name="about" class="input-medium" placeholder="About this food">
    <input type="number" id="num" name="num" class="input-medium" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" placeholder="Price">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
  </form>
```

I cant seem to figure the problem.

Comment: And what does `mysql_error()` say after inserting? If the `ID` column is set as unique, inserting the same session id will likely fail. Also, why is there no escaping for your input variables when you use the cumbersome mysql_ interface?

Answer (score 0):

I believe 'id' is a primary field for the table and you try to insert the same record to the table. So its not inserting the record to the table. If you want to modify the record with new values try for update query by checking the condition like record already exist.

If you use below one, you can track the mysql error.

mysql_query($sql) or die($sql . mysql_error());

Comment: yeah you are right. but in my DB i didnt set the ID colum to be the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but notice that on your form, your action is `inser` instead of `insert`.

In your database, you did set `id` to auto increment, right? If you are using `$_SESSION['id']`, it is obviously going to try and insert the data into the rows with the id equal to the session ID, that's why it can only insert once.